# Bootstrap 4 navbar with asp.net web.sitemap; how to remeove the dots?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have an asp.net web application; I was using sitemap for menu controller. Then I decided to use bootstrap navbar; and now I am trying to implement bootstrap 4.1 to asp.net menu controller with sitemap.

I have already achieved to bind the asp.net Menu controller from a sitemap; and style it with bootstrap 4.1; but I have dots coming before every the menu item letters; and I could not remove them (please see the picture).

I need help to remove these dots from my menu aspect. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Here goes my code**:

```
<!-- Menu BAŞI -->
<nav class="afiniteksMenuNavbar navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" EnableViewState="false" />
   <div class="NBCollapse collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="horizontal"
         DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
         IncludeStyleBlock="False"
         CssClass="afiniteksNav navbar-nav" StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav-item"
         StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="nav-item" StaticSubMenuIndent="16px"
         DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="nav-item dropdown-menu"
         RenderingMode="List" role="menu" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
         <LevelMenuItemStyles>
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="dropdown-item" HorizontalPadding="15px" Height="50px" VerticalPadding="15px" />
         </LevelMenuItemStyles>
         <LevelSelectedStyles>
            <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="nav-item active" Font-Underline="False" />
         </LevelSelectedStyles>
         <StaticHoverStyle Font-Underline="true" />
         <StaticSelectedStyle Font-Bold="true" />
         <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="dropdown-item" />
      </asp:Menu>
   </div>
</nav>
<!-- Menu SONU -->
</div>
```

[image]

Here goes the compiled html code:

```
 <div class="col-md-8" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                        <!-- Menu BAŞI -->

                        <div class="ortalaVH">
                        <nav class="afiniteksMenuNavbar navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">

                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>

                            <div class="NBCollapse collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                                <a href="#Menu1_SkipLink"><img alt="Gezinti Bağlantılarını Atla" src="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/WebResource.axd?d=Nd69XRQ7kJaHjjr-OjgVxjrB03FYSGQ7QiO79mNpEUi5Set0fmG4nYg5ZIDyqae_peFkIA3_jV-FbQB4KaDCfPTVsUgbnhfE1Z15KY2vxEo1&amp;t=636590973156695494" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;"></a><div role="menu" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" class="afiniteksNav navbar-nav" id="Menu1" style="float: left;">
    <ul class="level1 nav-item static" tabindex="0" role="menubar" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;">
        <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a title="AnaSayfa" class="level1 dropdown-item static" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/" tabindex="-1">AnaSayfa</a></li><li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:3" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a title="Tanımlamalar Bölümü" class="popout level1 dropdown-item static" tabindex="-1">Tanımlar</a><ul class="level2 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:3" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
            <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a title="Tanımlamalar Bölümü" class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/AnaPanel/SabitTanimlama.aspx" tabindex="-1">Sabit Tanımlama</a></li><li class="has-popup dynamic" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:5" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;"><a title="Cari Bölümü" class="popout level2 dropdown-item dynamic" tabindex="-1">Cari</a><ul class="level3 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:5" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 100%;">
                <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Cari/CariTanimlama.aspx" tabindex="-1">Tanımlama</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Cari/CariGuncelleme.aspx" tabindex="-1">Güncelleme</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Cari/CariListesi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Cari listesi</a></li>
            </ul></li><li class="has-popup dynamic" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:10" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;"><a title="Stok Kartları Bölümü" class="popout level2 dropdown-item dynamic" tabindex="-1">Ürün / Hizmet</a><ul class="level3 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:10" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 100%;">
                <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/StokKarti/UrunTanimlama.aspx" tabindex="-1">Tanımlama</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/StokKarti/UrunGuncelleme.aspx" tabindex="-1">Güncelleme</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/StokKarti/UrunListesi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Liste</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        </ul></li><li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:16" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a title="Pazarlama Bölümü" class="popout level1 dropdown-item static" tabindex="-1">Pazarlama</a><ul class="level2 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:16" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
            <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Pazarlama/SiparisIslemleri.aspx" tabindex="-1">Sipariş İşlemleri</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Pazarlama/SiparisRaporu.aspx" tabindex="-1">Sipariş Raporları</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Pazarlama/IsletmeHareket.aspx" tabindex="-1">İşletme Hareket - Tümü</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item selected dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Pazarlama/SiparisAnaliz.aspx" tabindex="-1">Sipariş Analiz - Tümü</a></li>
        </ul></li><li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:22" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a title="Satın Alma Bölümü" class="popout level1 dropdown-item static" tabindex="-1">Satın Alma</a><ul class="level2 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:22" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
            <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/SatinAlma/SA_SiparisGiris.aspx" tabindex="-1">SA - Sipariş İşlemleri</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/SatinAlma/SA_SiparisRaporu.aspx" tabindex="-1">SA - Sipariş Raporları [TR]</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/SatinAlma/SA_SiparisRaporu_EN.aspx" tabindex="-1">SA - Sipariş Raporları [EN]</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/SatinAlma/SA_SiparisListesi.aspx" tabindex="-1">SA - Sipariş Listesi</a></li>
        </ul></li><li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:28" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a title="Depo Bölümü" class="popout level1 dropdown-item static" tabindex="-1">Depo</a><ul class="level2 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:28" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
            <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/DepoCikis.aspx" tabindex="-1">Depo Çıkış</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/DepoCikisAnaliz.aspx" tabindex="-1">Depo Çıkış Analiz</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/DepoCikisFisi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Depo Çıkış Fişi</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/EtiketYazdir.aspx" tabindex="-1">Etiket Yazdır</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/LotEtiketiYazdir.aspx" tabindex="-1">Lot Etiketi Yazdır</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/DepoGiris.aspx" tabindex="-1">Depo Giriş</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/LotIslemleri.aspx" tabindex="-1">Lot İşlemleri</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/StokDurumListesi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Stok Durumu</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/LotStokDurum.aspx" tabindex="-1">Lotlu Stok Durumu</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/LotluStokListeleme.aspx" tabindex="-1">Lotlu Stok Listeleme</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Depo/DepoLokasyon.aspx" tabindex="-1">Lokasyon</a></li>
        </ul></li><li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:41" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a title="Evrak Düzenleme Bölümü" class="popout level1 dropdown-item static" tabindex="-1">Evrak Düzenleme</a><ul class="level2 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:41" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
            <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Evrak/ProformaTR.aspx" tabindex="-1">Proforma [TR]</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Evrak/ProformaEN.aspx" tabindex="-1">Proforma [EN]</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Evrak/IrsaliyeliFaturaTR.aspx" tabindex="-1">Fatura [TR]</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Evrak/CekiListesi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Çeki Listesi [TR]</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Evrak/IrsaliyeliFaturaEN.aspx" tabindex="-1">Fatura [EN]</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Evrak/PackingListEN.aspx" tabindex="-1">Packing List [EN]</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Evrak/CariEkstre.aspx" tabindex="-1">Cari Ekstre</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Evrak/CariEkstrePDF.aspx" tabindex="-1">Cari Ekstre PDF</a></li>
        </ul></li><li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:51" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a title="Muhasebe Bölümü" class="popout level1 dropdown-item static" tabindex="-1">Muhasebe</a><ul class="level2 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:51" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
            <li class="has-popup dynamic" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:52" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;"><a title="KASA" class="popout level2 dropdown-item dynamic" tabindex="-1">Kasa</a><ul class="level3 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:52" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 100%;">
                <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Kasa/TahsilatFisi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Tahsilat Fişi</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Kasa/OdemeFisi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Ödeme Fişi</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Kasa/GiderFisi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Gider Fişi</a></li>
            </ul></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Muhasebe/IrsFatListesi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Satış Faturaları Listesi</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a title="Giderler Listesi" class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Muhasebe/GiderListesi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Giderler Listesi</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a title="Mutabakat Formları" class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/Muhasebe/BaBs.aspx" tabindex="-1">BA-BS Formu</a></li>
        </ul></li><li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:61" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a title="Yönetim Bölümü" class="popout level1 dropdown-item static" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/yonet" tabindex="-1">Yönetim</a><ul class="level2 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:61" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
            <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/yonet/OrtaklarHesabi.aspx" tabindex="-1">Ortaklar Hesabı</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/yonet/ortaklarHH.aspx" tabindex="-1">Ortaklar HH</a></li><li class="has-popup dynamic" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:64" role="menuitem" style="position: relative;"><a title="Goba" class="popout level2 dropdown-item dynamic" tabindex="-1">GOBA</a><ul class="level3 nav-item dropdown-menu dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:64" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 100%;">
                <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/goba/access/users.aspx" tabindex="-1">Settings</a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a class="level3 dropdown-item dynamic" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/client" tabindex="-1">Client Zone</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul>
</div><div style="clear: left;"></div><a id="Menu1_SkipLink"></a>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                        </div>


                        <!-- Menu SONU -->
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the compiled html code not asp template

Comment: Already added the compiled html code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with changing the following code:

```
IncludeStyleBlock="False"
```

to:

```
IncludeStyleBlock="true"
```

Many thanks for to you all for trying to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET menu system is ugly.

This is an block of html from the BS4 documentation:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    ...
```

Compare to ASP.NET combined with BS4:

```
<div class="NBCollapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <a href="#Menu1_SkipLink"><img alt="Gezinti Bağlantılarını Atla" src="" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;"></a>
  <div role="menu" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" class="afiniteksNav navbar-nav" id="Menu1" style="float: left;">
    <ul class="level1 nav-item static" tabindex="0" role="menubar" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;">
      <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative; float: left;">
        <a title="AnaSayfa" class="level1 dropdown-item static" href="/afiniteks.com/WebApp/" tabindex="-1">AnaSayfa</a>
      </li>
      ...
```

Right off the top all the BS4 classes wind up in unexpected places.  For instance take the  `<ul>` tags which are supposed to be classed as `.navbar-nav` not `nav-item`

Bootstrap 4 `.navbar-nav`class, among other things, contains this style:

```
.navbar-nav {
  ...
  list-style: none;
}
```

This is directly due to how ASP renders their menu system.

You might be able to get away with creating your own CSS to set `list-style: none;` for the menu system but I'd be surprised if it's that easy.

And aside from styling conflicts you may also run into JS conflicts as the ASP Menus also has its own JS